# Cannot restore the snapshot due to option group issue

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

There's an rds instance which uses ms sql ee with a database that uses TDE

The rds itself is configured with the option group which has the TDE option within it and the snapshot gets created with the same option group by default

The problem is that regardless of what option group the snapshot is configured with, during the restoration process you can choose only the default option group, which neither has TDE option nor can be reconfigured to have one, which in turn leads to "The requested instance must be associated with an option group that contains the persistent option TDE." error when hitting restore button being impossible to be resolved within the current "framework".

How can I successfully restore the snapshot?

Comment: Have you tried using the [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot.html) and specifying the **option-group-name** parameter to use your TDE option group? Does this work, or throw an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a chain of actions I had to perform in order to have a full list of options group:

1. Create brand new option group, add tde option to it
2. Copy your instance's snapshot with this option group
3. Try to restore this copy, full list of available option groups should appear in restoration page

If you experience the same issue I've encountered, you should keep in mind that there're might be "limitations"/"inconveniences" to this solution, which you might or might not encounter. Here're some I've observed myself:

- restoration process works only once, if you would need to restore again, you would have to go through the process all over again with creating new option group
- if you for some reason reload restoration page, you won't see full list of option groups again and would have to start anew
- there also seems to be limitations pertaining amount of restoration tries or amount of time from snapshot creation time before full list of option groups disappears from restoration process

General rule is that you should start the restoration process asap after the snap is created.